# How to convert .ui file to py by PyQt5.uic?

Tags: python

I tried to convert `.ui` file to `.py` using `loadUiTypem` , but it's not working

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import*
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.QtCore import*
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
import sys


MainUI,_ = loadUiType('main.ui')

class Main(QMainWindow,MainUI):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
       super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
       QMainWindow.__init__(self)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    main()`enter code here
```

> `raceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/korish/PycharmProjects/library/index.py", line 8, in <module>
>       MainUI,_ = loadUiType('main.ui',"rb")
>     File "C:\Users\korish\PycharmProjects\library\venv\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 199, in loadUiType
>       winfo = compiler.UICompiler().compileUi(uifile, code_string, from_imports, resource_suffix, import_from)
>     File "C:\Users\korish\PycharmProjects\library\venv\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Compiler\compiler.py", line 111, in compileUi
>       w = self.parse(input_stream, resource_suffix)
>     File "C:\Users\korish\PycharmProjects\library\venv\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 1013, in parse
>       document = parse(filename)
>     File "C:\Users\korish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
>       tree.parse(source, parser)
>     File "C:\Users\korish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
>       source = open(source, "rb")
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'main.ui'`

Comment: Not much to be said here: this file is not present where your code expects it to be. Please show your directory structure, the command you're using to run this and the directory you're running it from

Comment: it simply can't find `'main.ui'`. You can use `'/full/path/to/main.ui'`